# Selecting and manipulating all elements in list of custom class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, lambda

I have a list of custom class. The custom class contains a number of fields. I want to return the entire list but manipulate some of the fields and return all other fields  unchanged. Lets say my class has 10 fields:

Here my attempts:

```
List<custom> data = somedatalist;
data.Select(a=> a.field1 = a.field1 * 6).Select(a => a.field10 = field10*7).tolist()
```

This doesnt work because I dont select all elements in the first select.

I could do:

```
Select( a = > new Custom{....}).ToList();
```

But then I need to rewrite all fields, which seems cumbersome if I want to leave most of them as is and only manipulate say 2 out of 10.

Next attempt:

```
List<custom> data = somedatalist;
data.ForEach(a=> a.field1 = a.field1 * 6 && a => a.field10 = field10*7).tolist()
```

Also doesnt work, dont really know why. Also if I replace "&&" by "," it doesnt work.

I would appreciate other suggestions than:

```
Select( a = > new Custom{....}).ToList();
```

thanks!

Comment: `manipulate some of the fields ` Then don't use LINQ but a loop.

Comment: fine, I guess I could do this easily in an extension method, but I was in the linq mode...:)

Comment: well, to my understanding the first select filters for only field1, so if I do the second select the data doesnt contain the remaining fields any more

Comment: LINQ is a query language while you are trying to update the original list. If you want to project the original to another form, you have to create a new object. Either that, or modify the original

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
data.ForEach(a => {
    a.field1 = a.field1 * 6;
    a.field10 = a.field10 * 7;
});
```

Or equivalently:

```
data.ForEach(a => {
    a.field1 *= 6;
    a.field10 *= 7;
});
```

Note that the [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is not part of Linq. It's a member of the `List<T>` class. There's also no need to call `ToList` at the end—in fact you can't because the return type of `ForEach` is `void`.

This will modify all the items in the original list. If you'd like to create a list of modified objects, leaving the original unmodified, then creating a new object with standard Linq methods is the way to go:

```
var newList = data.Select(a => new Custom {
    field1 = a.field1 * 6,
    field2 = a.field2, 
    ...
    field9 = a.field9, 
    field10 = a.field10 * 7,
});
```

If you need to write many such queries and you don't like to type all the field names every time, you can create a kind of copy constructor:

```
public class Custom {
    public Custom(Custom other)
    {
        this.field1 = other.field1;
        this.field2 = other.field2;
        ...
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
var newList = data.Select(a => new Custom(a) {
    field1 = a.field1 * 6,
    field10 = a.field10 * 7,
});
```

Comment: thanks! and this returns also field2-field9 unchanged? will data be still of type List<custom> given you use anonymous type?

Comment: @nik There are no anonymous types here. The `a => { ... }` is a multi-statement lambda expression.

Comment: @nik: But note that you should not use `ToList` to create a `List<T>` just to be able to use `List.ForEach`. `ToList` creates a new collection which is redundant.